# When, if at all, to reset the state of an LSTM when training and when testing?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, lstm

I am building an LSTM that takes in time-series financial data. My dataset is made up of IDs (each ID is a certain stock), and timestamps. For each ID at each timestamp, there are a number of features and a label.

My LSTM takes in as input batches of shape (50, 25, 108). The 50 corresponds to 50 different IDs, 25 corresponds to 25 timestamps for each of these IDs, all over the same parallel 25 points in time and the 108 corresponds to the 108 features I have for each ID at each timestamp which can influence its price. Each timestamp also has a label, y. For each of these 50 sequences of 25 timestamps, my LSTM is is trying to predict the value of y at this 25th timestamp - the last label of the sequence.

So, in short, my network takes in 50 different sequences across the same 25 points in time, and so the RNN is unrolled over 25 time steps and uses the output of the last as its prediction.

For the sake of simplicity, say my training dataset consists of 9 IDs and 25 timestamps and instead of my LSTM taking input of shape [50, 25, 108] it is instead [3, 5, 108]. Therefore, I would batch this data and pass it through my LSTM as 3 IDs over 5 timestamps (i.e each batch would  be 3 sequences spanning the same 5 timestamps parallel in time). So the first batch would be IDs 0, 1 and 2, each over timestamps 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. The next batch would be the same IDs over timestamps 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. I would pass through 5 of these batches so that all 25 timestamps for these 3 IDs have gone through the network. It is at this point that I would reset the state of the LSTM, and then pass in 5 batches across IDs 3, 4, and 5.

Is this the correct thinking of when to reset the LSTM's state - at the beginning of each time series? My thinking is that for each batch along the 25 timestamps for a given ID, the LSTM's memory is valuable as these timestamps proceed the timestamps of the previous batch. However, when I then move to timestamp 0 of a new set of IDs, as this is the first timestamp in my data, the LSTM cannot use its memory from previous points in time to influence its predictions, and so the state of the LSTM is reset.

Secondly, once my LSTM has been trained and I am now testing its accuracy on unseen data without tuning and optimising its parameters, do I still use the same logic behind resetting the state? Do I continue to reset it each time I pass in the first timestamp of an ID? Or should resetting only be performed when training?

Comment: You can improve this question by explaining your predictor/response data in standard language. For example, you could say that you have $n$ observations of $p$ stock returns. This data can then be arranged into an n-by-p matrix $X$ which can be fed into the LSTM, provided a response vector $Y$. You should also tell us a little more about what you are actually trying to do/predict. Also, your particular method of pooling different stocks' data does not quite make sense to me, and I don't understand why you'd use such a tiny batch size (three). A little more info on that would help as well.

Comment: @Josh I have added further details to my post.

Comment: So the idea is that all 50 IDs share a similar predictor-response relationship? Then it doesn't actually matter that you have multiple IDs; basically, you have some number of predictor time series and a single response value for each series. So you want the model to train on each sequence separately; by that I mean that from one sequence to another the *weights* will update, but the *state* must be reset. When predicting, you should reset the state to zero at the beginning of each sequence since you've already decided that the response depends only on the 25 values provided.

Comment: @Josh so my thinking is correct that I process an ID across all of its timestamps, and then reset the state when moving onto a new ID?

Comment: No, I don't think that's right. Your conjecture is that some combination of the 25 predictor observations from a particular sequence (and not the observations from other sequences) has a relationship to the single response observation, correct? If that's so, then you don't want the network to "remember" its *state* (not to be confused with the *weights*) from one sequence to the next, and you'd want to reset it after training on each sequence. Otherwise, the short term memory (state) evolves such that information from previous sequences will affect predictions on the next sequence.

Comment: @Josh Yes, that is correct. But 25 is just the arbitrary number of time steps that my network is unrolled into. Each ID can span over a continuous range of far greater than 25 timestamps. So say I pass in a sequence of timestamps 0-24 that ID 10 spans over, in the next batch I will be passing in timestamps 25-49 of ID 10. This second sequence follows directly in time to the first sequence and so is dependent on the first sequence, hence why I am thinking that this state should be passed from the first to the second sequence.

Comment: However, when all timestamps of ID 10 have gone through the network, I next want to pass through ID 11. ID 11 is completely independent from ID 10, and so I do not want the LSTM's state to be passed from when it was processing ID 10, so before passing any sequences from ID 11 into the network, I would reset the state.

Comment: Okay, that's a different scenario. If back-to-back sequences represent continuous evolution of some process (stock returns, maybe), then I agree you should not reset the state until you move onto another stock/ID. But then I would want to know why you only have one response value for each sequence; it would seem that you should have a response value for each predictor observation, and just allow the network to evolve through the first 25 observations before giving it a response value (which is equivalent to not penalizing loss on the first 24 response observations, if they were provided).

Comment: I see. So currently, my LSTM is unrolled across 25 time steps, each taking in input at the timestamp proceeding the that of the previous unrolled time step. Each of these 25 time steps produces an output, and I have a label for each, but I am ignoring the first 24 and only calculating my loss on the last prediction. Should I instead be recognising all predictions across the 25 timesteps and calculating the error across all?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's a better bet. You're literally multiplying your number of observations by 25 that way, so your model training should be vastly superior. Just to be clear though, what you describe as "unrolling" doesn't jive with my understanding of LSTMs. You shouldn't need to break up a sequence into smaller sequences. You should be able to just give it the full sequences of predictors and response values and that's it. Are you doing this in Keras?

Comment: @Josh Ok I will try that and see if there are improvements, which I now believe there will be. I am using TensorFlow alone. By unrolling, I mean the idea behind this: https://kvitajakub.github.io/img/rnn-unrolled.png - when I say "the network is unrolled to 25 time steps" I simply mean that it takes in a sequence of length 25.

Comment: @Josh In terms of my original question - after training, and I am now testing my  model, should I follow the same idea when resetting the state?

Comment: That's what I thought. Do you have to limit it to some number of observations or can you just give it the full sequence? LSTMs should only need the cell outputs at $t-1$, state at $t$, and the predictor values at $t$ in order to make a forecast for $t+1$. Therefore, there's no reason to break up the data into smaller sequences unless there's some feature that makes them naturally separate. As for prediction, yes, let the state evolve continuously just like in training, but *separately* for different stocks (i.e., set to zero at the beginning of each stock's time series).

Comment: Note that the way the LSTM retains information for observations prior to $t-1$ is via the state, that is, the state at $t$ will contain information about every set of observations fed into it since the last reset.

Comment: @Josh so if some of my stocks span ~1800 timestamps you're saying that I can just pass a sequence of the full length of 1800 into my LSTM in one go? I would make 1800 separate predictions for each of these timestamps in the sequence  and  calculate  my loss across all of  them. I was under the impression that if the LSTM is unrolled too long, then it can causes problems similar to the vanishing gradient in vanilla RNNs.

Comment: Yeah, I think you should at least try that first. What I would do is set the "weight" (i.e. contribution to loss metric calculation) on the first 24 observation-response pairs to zero, because you're assuming that the model will always have a history of at least 25 observations when it makes predictions. Since you were planning on keeping the state across 25-observation sequences anyway, this is mathematically equivalent to that approach (unless you are using some unique LSTM implementation where the inputs from observations prior to $t-1$ are fed directly; personally I wouldn't do this).

Comment: By the way, this is exactly how LSTMs avoid the gradient saturation problem: only the predictor values from $t$ and $t-1$ are used directly and the earlier observations' information is represented by the state, rather than having some fixed number of past outputs fed back in as inputs, with the gradient flattening with each "recurrence."

Comment: I'm confused with how you explained to set the weight on the first 24 sequences to 0. From the way I explained earlier that I am batching several IDs across 25 timespans at a time, then after each batch, the loss calculated is used in the backpropagation to tune the weights. So the weights are updated after every sequence of 25. If I was inputting the full sequences of length 1800, then conceptually my batches would be of length 1800. So the loss would be calculated across the 1800 timestamps and then the weights would only be updated after these 1800.

Comment: I feel like this would be of no benefit, and may even perform worse than batching into sequences of length 25. By batching into lengths of 25, then my weights are updated more frequently, thus improving accuracy, and by passing the state between batches, this would simulate the same idea as passing in all 1800 timestamps at once.

Comment: Anyway, I will test out both options over the weekend and let you know how they perform.

Comment: Also, if you are interested in seeing my model, and perhaps may have an answer to my TensorFlow related question, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46734916/4564080

Comment: I put "weight" in quotes because I am not taking about network weights, I'm talking about the *weight* assigned to those observations when evaluating the loss function. That way you're getting 1776 training instances, and you can be sure that the *state* of the model has evolved through at least 25 observations. If you allow nonzero weight to the first 24 observations, the model is penalized for prediction error on those observations; this doesn't seem like what you want because in reality you'll be giving it a history of at least 25 observations prior to its first prediction.

Comment: @Josh Ok, I understand. I'm still unsure if there's any benefit to putting in all 1800 inputs at once rather than batching them into 25 at a time, as long as I am passing the final state from one batch to the next.

Comment: Also, note that there isn't necessarily any dependence on the number of elements in your sequence and the number of gradient updates. I could compute the loss and gradient at the 25th observation, make a parameter (network weight) update, then compute the loss and gradient at the 26th, make another parameter update, and so forth (online learning, basically). Or I could wait until I had some number of predicted values and compute the gradient update from all of them at once. It doesn't have anything to do with sequence length.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I was under the impression that updating the weights after every time step such as in online training would converge to a higher accuracy faster than only updating the weights after some length sequence. It is just, obviously, far more computationally expensive. By the way, I never mentioned that the max sequence length of IDs is 1800, but some are far shorter - some are even shorter than 25. Since the network has to have a fixed input size, I would regularly have to add large paddings to the sequences if the network width was 1800.

Comment: I think this may be getting beyond the scope of what can be discussed effectively through chat/comments, but the sequence length thing shouldn't matter unless you are trying to make this parallelizable across IDs/stocks (and it's implementation-specific). If it's being done serially, it does not matter at all. Keep in mind that it's impossible to parallelize individual IDs (only across IDs), since the state is totally path dependent since inception.

Comment: I agree. I'm learning through everything, so all of your replies have helped me. Thank you, I'm looking forward to experimenting with what we discussed.

Comment: The matrix multiplication stuff could be parallelized within the computation of a particular prediction, but you couldn't parallelize the prediction at $t$ and $t+1$, because the prediction at $t+1$ depends on the output at $t$.

Comment: omg, thats a lot of comments to read through :O

Comment: I felt the question wasn't quite specific enough to answer directly so...this is what happened instead.